# Submitting form edited values ngForm

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to submit a form with some default value in the form field already initialized. My HTML code looks like:

```
<form #updateEndpointForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="updateEndpoint(updateEndpointForm);">
            <section class="form-block">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="id" name="id" [value]="updateEndpointData?.id" [hidden]="true" ngModel required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="endPointType">Endpoint Type</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Endpoint Type" name="endPointType" [value]="updateEndpointData?.endPointType" ngModel required readonly>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Endpoint Name</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Endpoint Name" name="name" [value]="updateEndpointData?.name" ngModel required>
                </div>
            </section>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">ADD</button>
        </form>
```

On the HTML page I am able to get the data in the corresponding field showing in the UI. The problem here I am facing is: Whenever I am submitting the form, the value of `console.log(updateEndpointForm.value);` is coming as empty `{"id":"","name":"","endPointType":""}`. Only the field which I actually modify is coming with the data. I want all the values which I got from `updateEndpointForm` How I can get that? Edit: I don't want to use two way binding `[(ngModel)]`.

Comment: Why aren't you using `[(ngModel)]` in the form fields?

Comment: I can't use two way data binding. I have too many forms in the same template with same fields.

Comment: [value] its called property binding. So you can't get value after changed. Then only using simply [(ngModel)] for both property binding and event binding. Still u can't use let's try https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms Reactive Forms.

Comment: But you are not mentioned without two way data binding in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working solution using Two way data binding,

Html File,

```
<form #updateEndpointForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="updateEndpoint(updateEndpointForm);">
  <section class="form-block">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="endPointType">Id</label>        
          <input type="text" placeholder="id" name="id"  [hidden]="true" [(ngModel)]="updateEndpointData.id" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="endPointType">Endpoint Type</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Endpoint Type" name="endPointType" [(ngModel)]="updateEndpointData.endPointType" required readonly>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Endpoint Name</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Endpoint Name" name="name" [(ngModel)]="updateEndpointData.name" required>
      </div>
  </section>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">ADD</button>
</form>
```

Typescript File,

```
//here iam declared sample variable with data
public updateEndpointData:any={"id":1,"name":"Muthu","endPointType":"test"};

updateEndpoint(data){
    console.log("form data",data.value);
}
```

Output Screenshot,
Note, Iam declared variable value "Muthu" run time iam changed "Muthukumar" and here is output.

[image]

Here is an stackblitz working example.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2mqjyk

Comment: If you can add a plunker or a stackblitz for this. It would be usefull for others.

Comment: Any other way without using two way binding?